# calling android function in sencha touch controller

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

Sencha Touch Controller JavaScript:

```
test:function(name)
{
    alert("function called");
    window.AndroidFunction.playAudio(name);
    alert("completed");
},
```

Android JavaScriptHandler:

```
public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
Context mContext;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public void playAudio(String path)
{
    System.out.println("path "+path);
    try {
        int resID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(path, "raw", mContext.getPackageName());
        if(mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }   

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, resID);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR in Play Audio : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

i m calling android function from sencha touch controller function
but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are You trying Run Your Application in emulator or device.

In my case I am trying to run in emulator its not working but in device it works perfectly.